# missing ) after argument list - how do I fix it in this simple code I keep changing things and get dif errors but cant figure this one out

Tags: javascript

This is the code we were given to create a program but it is not working can any one help?

```
var rad; var pi,item, total; var area, item, total; var circum, item, total;
rad = readNumber("Please enter the radius of a circle");
pi = 3.1416;
area = rad * rad * pi;
circum = 2 * rad * pi;
printLine ("The radius you entered is"rad);
printLine ("The area of the circle is"area);
printLine ("The circumference is"circum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use concatenation:

```
printLine("The radius you entered is" + rad);
```

See the `+`.